# How to retrive the text : No movie by this actor

Tags: php, get-posts

Hy, im building a cinema site, in movie page i have a Custom Field that link's the actor page, when i add a movie and i link the actor, on the actor page i get the movie, now the problem is  how can i add in this code the text "No movie by this actor", if no movie is selected i want to retrive automate That Text.

To retrive the movies i have this code.

```
<?php 
//create new loop query for films by this actor
$movies = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'distributie' AND meta_value LIKE '%".get_the_ID()."%'");
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $movies) );


// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<div class="actor-box-related"><a class="actor-titlu" href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
    ?>
    <img class="actor-img" src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img'); ?>&h=110&w=75&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  title="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>

    <?php the_title();
    echo '</a></div>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Anny help would be apreciate.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts()){  
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="actor-box-related"><a class="actor-titlu" href="';
        the_permalink();
        echo '" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
        ?>
        <img class="actor-img" src="/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_field('img'); ?>&h=110&w=75&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  title="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>

        <?php the_title();
        echo '</a></div>';
    endwhile; 
} else {
    echo("No movie by this actor");
}
```